# Why Object "Adult" cannot be printed out?

Tags: java

```
package com.java.zha;

public class Person{

    private String name;

    public Person(){
    }

    public Person(String name1){
        this.name=name1;
    }

    public void printkk(){
        for (int i=0; i<3;i++){   
            System.out.println(Adult[i].name);/*the prompt message said that" the Adult              can not be resolved as an variant.*/
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person[] Adult= new Person[3];
        Adult[0]=new Person("zhangbin");
        Adult[1]=new Person("zhangchangqing");
        Adult[2]=new Person("nana");

        System.out.println(Adult[2].name);
        Adult[1].printkk();
    }
}
```

PS: I created an object `Adult` and a `printkk()` method which used to print       all the member's name of the `Adult` array. But it give me an error. So I ask help from your guys. I am just starting to code please answer it in detail. thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what's the error?  Where in the code is the error?

Comment: Because `Adult` is visible to only `main()` method. Please read about scope of variables...

Comment: @Codebender So how to rewrite the method to accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're trying to access private fields, change `private String name;` to `public String name;` or add a `getName()` method so that you can print out the name with `System.out.println(Adult[2].name);` or `System.out.println(Adult[2].getName();`.
2. Your `printkk()` method is trying to print out a non-existant `Adult` array.  You'll need to pass it as an argument to the method, so change `public void printkk()` to `public void printkk(Person[] Adult)` and then change `Adult[1].printkk();` to `Adult[1].printkk(Adult);`

This is probably the easiest way to get your code to work, but it would be better to scrap what you have and rewrite most of it.